# excel vba - sort pivot table if filter is changed

Tags: vba, excel, sorting, pivot-table

Is there a way to automatically sort a pivot table each time a given filter of the pivot table is changed?

I would like to sort a pivot table by the values in descending order in the 3rd column. The filter for this table is updated each month. As such I dont want to manually sort it each time.

Here is the vba code when I do it manually.

```
Sub example()
'
' example Macro
'
    Range("BO12").Select
    'change period filter from "3" to "4"
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Period")
        .PivotItems("3").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("4").Visible = False
    End With
    'sort the table in descending order by the values in the 3rd column
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Channel").AutoSort _
        xlDescending, "Sum of Shares", ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2"). _
        PivotColumnAxis.PivotLines(3), 1
End Sub
```

Is there a way to automate this?

Image of the table in question:

[image]

What I tried to no avail.

```
Private Sub SortTables(ByVal Target As Range)
'
' SortTables Macro
'
'
    Range("D12").Select
    If Target.Name = "PivotTable3" Then
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Channel").AutoSort _
        xlDescending, "Sum of Shares", ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3"). _
        PivotColumnAxis.PivotLines(3), 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You want to have the Pivot Table sorted according to the 3rd column ? what is the 3rd column `PivotFields.Name` ? is it `"Channel"`? you want to sort them by `"Channel"` values ?

Comment: The 3rd column contains contains data for the latest month. "Period" = "4" which is April. See image.

Comment: OK, so you want to sort `"Sum of Shares"` in Descending order, according `"Period" = "4"`  ? the output should be `7.11 , 1.18, 0.77, 0.32, 0.02` ?

Comment: Correct! The data for "Period" = "4" is in column 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below, it will `Sort` the Values according to `PivotFields("Period")` where `.PivotItems("3")` (you can easily modify it later to fit your needs).

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub example()

Dim PivTbl          As PivotTable
Dim PivFld          As PivotField
Dim RngKey1         As Range

' set the Pivot Table to an object
Set PivTbl = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2")

'change period filter from "3" to "4"
With PivTbl
    With .PivotFields("Period")
        .PivotItems("3").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("4").Visible = False
    End With

    ' set "Period" to a PivotField Object
    Set PivFld = .PivotFields("Period")

    ' set the SortRange to PivotItem "3" of PivotField "Period"
    Set RngKey1 = PivFld.PivotItems("3").DataRange

    ' sort the Pivot Table's values in escending order, according to PivotItem "3" column
    PivFld.PivotItems("3").DataRange.Sort key1:=RngKey1, Order1:=xlDescending, Type:=xlSortValues, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
End With

End Sub
```